# If $f$ is continuous, then $X$ and $\{(x,f(x)); x\in X\}$ (the domain and the graph of $f$) are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$. The graph of $f$ is the subset $G=\{(x,f(x))\}\subseteq X\times Y$. Show that if $f$ is continuous, then $X$ is homeomorphic to the graph of $f$.

My attempt: Let $h:X\to G$ by $h(x)=(x,f(x))$. The fact that $h$ is a bijection is clear. Now since $g:X\to X$ by $g(x)=x$ is continuous and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous by hypothesis, the universal mapping property of products says that $h$ must be continuous. I'm having trouble showing $h^{-1}$ is continuous though... $g^{-1}:X\to X$ is continuous by the same argument as for $g$, but how would I show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Older question about the same result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429797/if-f-is-continuous-then-g-is-homeomorphic-to-x

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $h^{-1}\colon G\to X$ maps $(x,f(x))$ to $x$. Therefore it can be obtained as the restriction of the projection $X\times Y\to X$ to the subspace $G$ of $X\times Y$. Projections are continuous, and so is an inclusion map of a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic idea is good, but try the composition $X\to X\times X \to X\times Y$ defined as follows  instead
$$
x\mapsto (x,x)\mapsto (x, f(x))
$$
Show that in each step you have a homeomorphism.