# Which of the following spaces are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

> > Let $X$ be a metric space and $f\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $G = \{ (x , f(x) ) : x \in X \}$ be the  graph of $f$. Then which one is true?

1. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$
2. $G$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$
3. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb R$
4. $G$  is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \times X$

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Take an easy space, say $X = [0,1]$, and an easy $f$. Then sketch, and look what cannot be right.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : Thanks, I will try it

Comment: After you solve the question, you might want to take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429797/if-f-is-continuous-then-g-is-homeomorphic-to-x.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: After working out an example as in Daniel Fischer's comment, study the following two natural maps:

- $\phi:X\rightarrow G$ given by $\phi(x)=(x,f(x))$,
- $\varphi:G\rightarrow X$ given by $\varphi(x,f(x))=x$.

In particular study their continuity and compute their compositions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x$ then $G=\{(x,x):x\in (0,1)\}$  which is a closed set  but $(0,1)$ is not

Again Consider $X=[0,1]$ which is compact and $f(x)=x$.Its graph is compact but $\mathbb R$ is not.

NOTE:Consider $f(x)=0$ .Then graph of $f=\{(x,0):x\in \mathbb R\}$ i.e. the $x$ axis .Now remove the point $(0,0)$ from the graph of $f$ ,it becomes disconnected   but $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is not.

Comment: @ learmoe : please tell me (3) is true or not

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your need @user120386

Comment: Be careful - $X=(0.1)$ may not be a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, but as a space itself it is closed.

Comment: @ Learner : Thank you so much

Comment: it would be great if you could accept my answer if you think so@user120386